# Install specific version of spacy - working with pip, but not with conda

Tags: python, conda, spacy

I am revisiting some code I wrote months ago with Spacy Version 2.1.8. I need this version of spacy. pip install is working but Anaconda does not even show that spacy is installed. And

```
conda install spacy=2.1.8
```

gives the PackagesNotFoundError error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [spaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage#conda), you can take advantage of the `conda-forge` community repository to install `spacy`

```sh
$ conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.1.8
```

This version should be available according to [spaCy's page on Conda Forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spacy/files).

Comment: Note that `conda-forge::spacy=2.1.8` is [only available for Python 3.6 or 3.7](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spacy/files?version=2.1.8).